# list @property decorated methods in a python class

Tags: python, properties, decorator, python-decorators

Is it possible to obtain a list of all `@property` decorated methods in a class? If so how?

Example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        pass
    @property
    def bar(self):
        pass
```

How would I obtain `['foo', 'bar']` from this class?

Answer (score 14):

Anything decorated with `property` leaves a dedicated object in your class namespace. Look at the `__dict__` of the class, or use the `vars()` function to obtain the same, and any value that is an instance of the `property` type is a match:

```
[name for name, value in vars(MyClass).items() if isinstance(value, property)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...     @property
...     def foo(self):
...         pass
...     @property
...     def bar(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> vars(MyClass)
dict_proxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'bar': <property object at 0x1006620a8>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'MyClass' objects>, 'foo': <property object at 0x100662050>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'MyClass' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>> [name for name, value in vars(MyClass).items() if isinstance(value, property)]
['bar', 'foo']
```

Note that this will include anything that used `property()` directly (which is what a decorator does, really), and that the order of the names is arbitrary (as dictionaries have no set order).